# Netlify saving images as>- https://raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

My netlify admin started saving images like this to the markdown files

```
image: >-
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/master/static/img/myimage.png
```

How do I change it to save like this? Otherwise, I need to manually change after each save in the admin.

```
image: /img/myimage.png
```

Comment: Are you dragging and dropping an image from a page hosted on github?

Comment: No, uploading from local device, or selecting one that's already been uploaded. When I open the image gallery in admin, all the images have that as the src attribute.

Comment: This is a known issue created in the last release (2.5.x) and [there is a proposed fix coming](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/pull/2147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue created in release (2.5.x)

Make sure to upgrade to the [fixed version](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/pull/2147) of `netlify-cms` `^2.6.0`